# Software for stitching together many short videos, and basic editing

Tags: video

I'd eventually like to

- edit 52*18=936 videos (one for each week of my son's life up til age 18) down to three seconds each
- stitch them together as a single video file
- add some music over it, and
- maybe add some text (e.g., dates).

I'd mildly prefer the following:

- desktop software (Windows) over mobile apps or web apps
- software that integrates with Google Photos
- software which is free
- software which doesn't have *that* steep of a learning curve

I've come across the following software:

CapCut, DaVinci Resolve, Kapwing, Adobe Express, OpenShot, Lightworks, Hitfilm Express, Blender.

There are puts and takes with each. What software would you recommend, on this list or otherwise?

Answer (score 3):

Of your requirements, the learning curve is rather arbitrary. With YouTube and other resources, the learning curve for your choice should not be a limiting factor.

Free means that [Kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/en/) fits that notch. It's platform flexible, Windows, MacOS, Linux, no mobile devices.

All of the other requirements are managed "easily enough" by Kdenlive, especially if you consider performing, for example, a search using terms such as "[Kdenlive add text to video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OxbV7-wCPrI)."

Consider that Blender is a 3D modeling program and to the best of my understanding, not a video editor.